# C game shutting down after user input

Tags: c, while-loop

I am working on a game where the user must change the letters in a word to make the target word using a cursor. My code is running but when the user input is taken the cursor does not move and the letters do not change. Symbols are printed before the next iteration of the loop just before "Game state".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "WordGame.h"

int main() {
    char  current_letters[] = {'b', 'e', 'l', 'l'};
    char target_letters[] = {'c', 'o', 'a', 't'};
    int position_of_cursor = 2;
    const int NUMBER_OF_LETTERS = 4;
    bool game_finished = false;
    int number_of_letter_changes = 0;
    int max = 3;

    while (number_of_letter_changes < 8) {
        display_game_state (target_letters, current_letters, NUMBER_OF_LETTERS, position_of_cursor, number_of_letter_changes);

        printf("Enter a command: ");
        char letter = get_user_char();

        if( letter == '>') {
            move_cursor_right(position_of_cursor, max);
        }
        else if ( letter == '<') {
            move_cursor_left(position_of_cursor, max);
        }

        move_cursor_right (&position_of_cursor, max);
        printf("%d", position_of_cursor);
        move_cursor_right (&position_of_cursor, max);
        printf("%d", position_of_cursor);
        number_of_letter_changes++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

WordGame.c code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

    char get_user_char() {
    //1. We create the output variable with the value the user has input by keyboard
    char res = getchar();

    //2. We discard any extra character the user has input by keyboard
    bool finish = false;
    char dummy_char = ' ';

    while (finish == false) {
        dummy_char = getchar();
        if (dummy_char == '\n')
            finish = true;
    }

    //3. We return the output variable
    return res;
}

    void display_game_state(char* pTarget_letters, char* pCurrent_letters,const int NUMBER_OF_LETTERS,
                            const int cursor_position, const int number_of_letter_changes)
        {
            printf("---Game State ---\n");
          //  printf("%p\n", pCurrent_letters);

            int c;

            printf("Target: ");

            for(c = 0; c <= 3; ++c) {

                printf("%c", *pTarget_letters);
                pTarget_letters = pTarget_letters + 1;

            }

            printf("\n-----------------\n");

            for(c = 0; c <= 3; ++c) {

                printf ("%c", *pCurrent_letters);
                pCurrent_letters = pCurrent_letters + 1;

            }

            int i;

            const char DASH = '-';
            const char SPACE = ' ';

            for(i = 0; i < cursor_position ; ++i) {

                printf("%c", SPACE);
            }

            printf("\n%c", DASH);

            printf("\nChanges: %d\n", number_of_letter_changes);

            char letter;
    }

    void move_cursor_right(int* pPosition_of_cursor, const int max)

    {

        printf ("%c", *pPosition_of_cursor);
        pPosition_of_cursor = pPosition_of_cursor + 1;

    }

    void move_cursor_left(int* pPosition_of_cursor, const int max)

    {

        printf ("%c", *pPosition_of_cursor);
        pPosition_of_cursor = pPosition_of_cursor - 1;

    }

    void change_letters(char* pLetters, int position, char new_letter, int max)

    {
        char* plocation_of_letter_to_change = pLetters + position;
    }

    void start_game(char * pCurrent,  char* pTarget, const int size_of_word)
{
    int position_of_cursor = 0;
    bool game_finished = false;
    int number_of_letter_changes = 0;

}
```

Comment: `if( letter = '>')` you need to use `==` for comparison.

Comment: Please explain why in one case `move_cursor_right(position_of_cursor, max);` and in another case `move_cursor_right (&position_of_cursor, max);`. Making a [mcve] could answer that, but better is to explain the API you imagine for that function.

Comment: Also, `printf(position_of_cursor);` and `printf("%d", position_of_cursor);` The first will very like cause a crash, since a `const char *` is expected. Please take note of compiler warnings.

Comment: Also, in `move_cursor_right (&position_of_cursor, max);` and others, `max` is *uninitialised*.

Comment: your program probably crashes in ~move_cursor_right` or `move_cursor_left`. Try running in a debugger like `gdb`.

Comment: Edited to fix above suggestions and I also included the wordgame.c code

Comment: Your code in `move_cursor_right` and `move_cursor_right` is wrong. The parameter `pPosition_of_cursor` is an `int*`, but you are treating it as an `int`.  Change your increment and decrement lines to be like this: `*pPosition_of_cursor = *pPosition_of_cursor + 1;`

Comment: @bruceg fixed my problem, thank you!